# Azure webjob ETIMEDOUT

Tags: azure-webjobs

I am running a dynamically triggered webjob it suddenly stopped by throwing **ETIMEDOUT** error I tried catching the error and increased the webjob idletime but unable to find a solution. Seems like the issue is with calls to external resource (I am not sure). I have not made any changes in the Azure portal or to the webjob code since long ago. Any help is much appreciated!

```
[06/11/2020 05:51:54 > abdbcb: INFO] { [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 130.248.148.130:443]
[06/11/2020 05:51:54 > abdbcb: ERR ]                             ^
[06/11/2020 05:51:54 > abdbcb: INFO]   code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
[06/11/2020 05:51:54 > abdbcb: INFO]   errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
```

Comment: It seems that it can not connect to `130.248.148.130:443`, what is this for?

Comment: Actually it is a CSV data processing functionality that takes the id from each row and ,fetches the related info of that id by SOAP requests .

Comment: Hi @Shankar, I responded to your post on Q&A. If you're pulling CSV data from 130.248.148.130:443 (which according whois.com is owned by Adobe, your webjob might be timing out waiting for the request to complete. Not sure what API you're calling, but to investigate, I would investigate any dependencies your webjob uses. You can temporarily add application insights to your webjob to determine which requests/processes are taking the longest amount of time.

Let mek know if I can be of further assistance

Comment: Thank you so much @RyanHill-MSFT. I will try to add application insights and let you know if I have any questions.